# Blender - Archipack Python - How to programmatically draw a wall?

Tags: python, scripting, archipack-add-on

I'm new to blender and have just discovered Archipack. I've done some coding in my past and was curious to see if there is an API(?) for Archipack? I've done some digging but haven't found anything solid yet.

I've found [this archipack link](https://s-leger.github.io/archipack/setup.html) but it doesn't seem to have much documentation on it regarding this topic. I'm basically just looking to see if I can put together a simple script that will create a square/rectangular room for starters.

Any and all help/direction is be appreciated.

Comment: The plugin is written in Python and source code is available in the scripts/addons/archimesh/ folder of your Blender install.

Comment: @RonJensen, I was hoping there was a simple tutorial somewhere with examples I could follow. Python isn't exactly my strongest language but thanks. I'll take a look and see what I can find.

Comment: Be careful Archimesh and Archipack are not the same add-on although they offer similar features. Are you using the pro or free (default shipped with Blender) version ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple example using an operator to create a 5u*5u square room in the Archipack version that's shipped with Blender :

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.archipack.wall2()  # This creates a simple wall span
o = bpy.context.active_object
m = o.data
prop = m.archipack_wall2[0]  # Access the Archipack wall object
prop.n_parts = 3  # Add 2 wall spans, they are automaticcaly added at a 90° angle
prop.closed = True  # Close the walls
for part in prop.parts:
    part.length = 5  # Increase the wall spans lengths
```

Result of running the script :

[image]

If you want a rectangular room, for instance, replace the last lines with :

```
for i, part in enumerate(prop.parts):
    part.length = 3 + (i % 2) * 3
```

[image]